# Calendar Control on Dynamically created forms

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, datepicker

I’m trying to accomplish a small task where I have one single Form ITERATED with a Date textinput which gets its Value by a Javascript DatePicker control.

My problem is, the datepicker on all these dynamically created forms only prints value on the first textbox element in the first form, how do I give it Dynamic reference to forms[x] text box element.

My form names are being generated Dynamically as form1, form2, form3, form[x], how do I reference the inner element of that particular form whose DatePicker is being clicked.
you can download the Zip file which has the datepicker & the HTML page for the Dynamic forms from here [enter link description here](http://scavansystems.com/test/dynamicForms.zip)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addElement() {
        intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
        intTextArea = intTextArea + 1;
        var contentID = document.getElementById("new-field-back");
        var newTBDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newTBDiv.onclick=function(){ current=this; }
        newTBDiv.setAttribute("id","strText"+intTextBox);
        newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<br/><br/><form method='post' name='form" + intTextBox + "'><input 

id='date_of_event' name='date_of_event" + intTextBox + "'  class='date-pick' value=''><div 

class='date-text'><a href='#' onclick=displayDatePicker('date_of_event" + intTextBox + 

"');>Calendar</a></div></div><input type='submit' value='Update'><input type='button' 

onclick='removeElement()' value='Remove'></form><br/><br/>";

        contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
    }
```

this is the correct function

Comment: use this corrected function in your script. there was a simple error. if you were creating forms with different names, the datepickers should also be given different names. error solved. dont forget to mark the answer correct if you like it.

Comment: Thx bro, but I'd like to keep the element ID's in the form same.. 
I may be wrong but if u can help me a little more, what I want to accomplish is that these individual forms, when submitted will run a MySql query & insert a row of Date & Event description into the Database.

My challenge here is how to Address the Value of these Dynamic element IDs ?? each form has its own Submit button but the element ID's change.....

Comment: if you keep the element id same then all the added calenders will modify the date of the same textbox. But this is not what you want. The calender control should modify the dates of their respective textboxes. Isnt it?

Comment: yes yes!!!...
but I need to RETRIEVE the value of the DATEBOX to POST it too a php file which will insert it into a DB
How to get the $_POST[date_of_event(x)]

Comment: its really simple dude. likewise u have done string manipulation to append the numbers to the field names, when you post the whole form, in the php file, run a loop to collect all the `$_POST['']` values by pushing variable names in a similar format. if you want i can post another answer with an example code too...

Comment: I may be wrong in my assumption but I wanted to avoid the LOOP if possible... see this is a module for posting latest updates on a site, its the admin section for that..
I want the admin to add an event, & then press update for it individually. is there a way to do it indiviudally for these forms ??
And Yes I'll be highly glad to see the example code... pls help me with it

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending all data using one click of a button then you need to add a hidden field on the html form containing the total number of dates to be sent.

```
$num=$_POST['no_of_dates'];
$i;
for ($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
    $_field_name="date_of_event".$i;
    $_date_get=$_POST[$_field_name];
    //now you can insert the $_date_get variable into the database by running a query.
}
```

Comment: I had initially thought of using some AJAX calls here on those individual forms, All I'm stuck is how to address the value of textboxes in the dynamically generated Form[x]
I'm pretty sure there is a way in Jquery to do it.... Only that I'm very noob to Jquery & JS

Comment: can you please upload all of your project and give me the instructions properly? i will solve this problem for you.